# Laravel & memcached

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, memcached

I have some interesting problem, that i cant solve alone.

On laravel 5.2 in AppServiceProvider i have

```
   $regionList = Cache::store('memcached')->get('regionList'); 

   if (empty($regionList)){
        $regions = new \App\Models\RegionalConfig();
        $regionList = $regions->getVersionsList()->toArray();
        Cache::store('memcached')->put('regionList', $regionList, 36000);
   }
```

and this perfectly works.

But if i put this part in any controller, my `$regionList` will be always empty. So, there is no insert in memcache.

Why this happend?

My config cache file:

```
'default' => env('CACHE_DRIVER', 'memcached'),
...
'memcached' => [
            'driver'  => 'memcached',
            'servers' => [
                [
                    'host' => env('MEMCACHED_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
                    'port' => env('MEMCACHED_PORT', 11211),
                    'weight' => 1000,
                ],
            ],
        ],
```

Comment: Have you tested with `has`. Have you looked (telnet) in memcached to see if the value is in fact stored? Is this an array? When serialized is it larger than 1 MB?

Comment: @ficuscr Telnet says me that there is no data with this key, but var_dump($regionList) after get('regionList') - shows me result

Comment: Have you checked your error logs? Ensure environment variable values are what you think?

Comment: @ficuscr logs says nothing, they are empty

Comment: Not to beat a dead horse, you're sure error reporting levels are sane? Maybe try a little division by zero?

Comment: @ficuscr also some information: yes, it's array. No, it's not larger than 1MB

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171722/discussion-between-ficuscr-and-sergiozhidkov).